# MaterializeCSS .container suddenly not working

Tags: css, materialize

My .container in materialize CSS always took up the entire screen.

```
            .container {
                width: 100%;
            }
```

but suddenly I opened it and it looks as though its back to the 70% container.

I thought maybe I accidentally deleted some code, but when I opened my back up of my website it too appeared as though the container was only 70% of the screen.  It's weird because it wasn't like that and now every page has a tiny container.  I tried making the container width bigger and it cuts things off my screen.  I also tried making all the rows wider but it just made my content stretch too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MaterializeCSS specifically defines the class `container` to be a max-width of `1280px` and a width of `90%`

Therefore, if you wish to still use this class but want it altered, you would either edit the `materialize.css` or in a separate `.css` file, declared UNDER the `materialize.css`:

```
.container{
    max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

You could also define these inline, however that is not recommended

Comment: Great, glad you can accept this answer as closed. Just remember when using outside css libraries, any file you declare last that has the SAME css selectors will take precedent over preceding rules declared.